# 22.4.3 text-to-video handover at boot failing (black screen); can you help me troubleshoot and correct please?

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel, 22.04, amd-graphics

## Background

1. I have reinstalled 22.04.3, as I want a vanilla system before trying to learn about various enterprise applications. I have been running Ubuntu since the initial release of 22.04; this is the first reinstall since then.
2. I am fairly technical, but I have reached the limits of what I can do, and I need help with understanding the root cause of this problem, and how to resolve it. Happy to follow guidance and paste results here so others can learn.
3. I have looked for a solution here and elsewhere, but there is no consensus as to root cause. There are a myriad of possible solutions, with no explanation on cause. There is no fault-finding procedure I can follow. Some say *linux-firmware*, or the kernel are the problem, whilst others recommend running AMD-specific drivers will solve the problem (personally I think this makes the problem worse). Even if it does solve the problem, you never know what the cause was.

## Problem

4. This is the main problem. Ubuntu is booting to a black screen. When *quiet* & *splash* are removed from Grub's kernel parameters, I see a quick listing of activity scroll on-screen, which then goes blank permanently.
5. On a fully functional system, said text scrolls, the screen blanks for a second, and the text is re-displayed more vibrantly. I think this is the video drivers kicking-in, hence the title of this post. Happy to be wrong; this is just my guess.
6. I can boot successfully using the latest kernel recovery option within Grub; I am typing this in recovery mode.
7. The only way I can install 22.04.3, is by using the latest kernel's safe graphics option. Choosing the normal option just results in a blank screen.

## What I have tried

8. When installing 22.04 on first release, there was a problem with iommu, requiring *amd_iommu=on* & *iommu=soft* in order for the screen to work. I have tried these options, on Grub's kernel line, in place of *quiet* & *splash*, as well as at the end of that line, after *vt_handoff* (not at the same time in both location), but nothing has worked.
9. I have reinstalled linux-firmware and amd64-microcode, followed by update-grub. Confidence levels were low when doing this, but I did it anyway. Problem unresolved.
10. I suspect that when Grub calls function *load_video*, **this** is where the failure is, but I don't know how to troubleshoot from there. It looks like module all_video is loaded by the kernel, if Grub cannot ascertain what video card is in use. It makes sense to have a catch-all.

```
function load_video {
if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
 insmod all_video
else
 insmod efi_gop
 insmod efi_uga
 insmod ieee1275_fb
 insmod vbe
 insmod vga
 insmod video_bochs
 insmod video_cirrus
fi
}
```

I then don't understand how the various modules correlate to AMD video drivers.

11. lshw seems to back up my theory; unsure if this is showing like this because I have booted into safe mode.

```
michael@mitp-NL5xRU:/var/log$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for michael: 
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Renoir
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: c3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf memory:fce0000000-fcefffffff memory:fcf0000000-fcf01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d0400000-d047ffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 2
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080
```

12. As does gpu-manager.log

```
og_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic/kernel
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic/updates/dkms
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic/kernel
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? no
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? no
Is nvidia kernel module available? no
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 1002:1636
BusID "PCI:4@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04:00.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver.
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 1
Has amd? yes
Has intel? no
```

## Hardware

```
H/W path                Device     Class          Description
=============================================================
/0/0                               memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/4                               processor      AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphics
/0/4/5                             memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/4/6                             memory         3MiB L2 cache
/0/4/7                             memory         8MiB L3 cache
/0/23                              memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/23/0                            memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/23/1                            memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/100                             bridge         Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
/0/100/0.2                         generic        Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
/0/100/8.1                         bridge         Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
/0/100/8.1/0                       display        Renoir
/0/100/8.1/0.1          card0      multimedia     Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.1/0        input31    input          HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/0/100/8.1/0.1/1        input32    input          HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/0/100/8.1/0.2                     generic        Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
/0/100/8.1/0.3                     bus            Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0        usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0/3                 input          USB Receiver
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0/3/0    input25    input          Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0/3/1    input26    input          Logitech Wireless Mouse
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1        usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.4                     bus            Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
/0/100/8.1/0.4/0        usb3       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.4/0/3                 communication  AX200 Bluetooth
/0/100/8.1/0.4/0/4      input27    multimedia     BisonCam,NB Pro: BisonCam,NB Pr
/0/100/8.1/0.4/1        usb4       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.5                     multimedia     Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
/0/100/8.1/0.6          card1      multimedia     Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.6/0        input33    input          HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone
```

## If possible

1. They say a little knowledge can be dangerous; if the above is complete rubbish, then I'm sorry  Can you point me to a detailed fault-finding procedure so I can follow, learn and correct please (if there is one)?
2. If there isn't one, can you help me troubleshoot this problem? I have tried to include above, what I think will help. If more information is required, please let me know.
3. Last but not least, thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Try temporarily disabling your display manager service via systemctl. Then reboot to find yourself a TTY where you can try to manually modprobe amdgpu, and look in dmesg to find out why it's not loading. You can also do startx (some config potentially needed) and see where that fails. Otherwise, look in journalctl for the last boot's errors